# Wordpress - Category not showing all posts

Tags: php, wordpress

```
        <?php
            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));

            if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
                $cats = get_the_category(); ?>
                <?php if ($cats[0]->cat_name === 'Coaching') { ?>
                <div class="callout horizontal">

                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                    <div class="content">
                        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

The above code is meant to only show categories that are from the category Coaching. However this happens for two of my category posts but not for the other three that are labeled under Category.

It is worth noting that I have set my reading posts in the wordpress settings to 9999 just incase this was a pagination problem.

Can anyone see what the error might be.

I would like to also mention that this logic was working not so long ago before I added a lot more posts.

Cheers

************** UPDATE ***************

To add to the mystery I have noticed that this is happening on another part of the site. Thats isn't related to the posts. But pulling out from Advanced Custom Fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

I've seen now that your post query will return all posts, and you're checking for category inside the loop, which is kinda redundant. Modify your query like this:

```
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query( 
                    array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'category_name' => 'coaching', //slug, not name!!
                        'posts_per_page' => 9999
                    )
                );
```

This will pull only posts from that category. :)

Comment: Nope. Loop will query your posts. Now that you've mentioned, I see that you've got the whole thing wrong. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Ha Thanks will implement once you've finished editing

Comment: This should do it. Just remember to put category slug, and not name in the query. Also try to avoid -1 in post per page parameter if possible. If you have really big number of posts it is a big query to execute. There is a great codex page about [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), and it's a great read

Comment: Woah! You've simplified that so much! Nice one thank you! Great Answer.

Comment: Just a real quick question. Lets say that I didn't want to show coaching but wanted to show all the other categories. Is there a simple way of doing that with the array?

Comment: There is a `category__not_in` parameter, but you'll need to specify array of category ID's that you want to exclude. So you'll need to find the ID of the coaching and add it like `'category__not_in' => array( X )` where X is the ID of the coaching cat (you can see the ID by hovering over the category)

Comment: Brilliant, I did read that one in the doc. I'll give it a play. Thanks for sharing your knowledge